# Postgres 11 INSERT ON CONFLICT SELECT *

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to insert a row into a table, if that insert succeeds I would to return the newly inserted row. If that insert fails, I would to select a row using some of the values I already know to be on that row.

For example, table 'reports' has 3 columns, so far I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO reports (col2, col3) VALUES ($1, $2) 
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT custom_index DO 
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE col1=$1 AND col2=$2;
```

For those who will ask, custom_index was created using:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX custom_index ON reports (col2) INCLUDE (col3);
```

The current error I am getting is

> syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Answer (score 2):

Select is not allowed in the conflict.

Check the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html.

Related question is already answered.. [Postgres 9.5 ON CONFLICT DO SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597668/postgres-9-5-on-conflict-do-select)