# How does Insert Into On Conflict Excluded Work?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, conflict

I can't find any good enough documentation on this, so I just thought I'd ask the Citizens of Stackoverflow.

Let's say I have the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.TABLE_A (id, user, active, last_login) --The ID column is the primary key
SELECT
     b.id, b.user, b.active, b.last_login
FROM
     PUBLIC.TABLE_B as B
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT ID_PKEY 
DO UPDATE
     user = excluded.user,
     active = excluded.active,
     last_login = excluded.last_login
```

Question 1) `user, active, and last_login come from PUBLIC.TABLE_A`, correct?

Question 2) `excluded.user, excluded.active, excluded.last_login` are the SAME EXACT records coming from `PUBLIC.TABLE_B` correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres 11 INSERT ON CONFLICT SELECT \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033073/postgres-11-insert-on-conflict-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect: it should be `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE SET "user" = EXCLUDED."user"`.

The `SET` points in the direction of the answer, since it is like the `SET` in an `UPDATE` statement. Yes, the columns to the left of the `=` (and which you cannot qualify with a table name) are the columns of the table that is to be updated, which is `public.table_a` in your case.

The pseudo-table `EXCLUDED` designates the row that you originally tried to insert, but that was rejected because of the conflict. In your case, that is a row from `public.table_b`.